# positive version of "resting on your laurels"

Tags: phrase-requests, idiom-requests

If someone has accomplished many outstanding achievements and established an incredible legacy, how can I say "I hope they finally found time to settle down and chill out, proud of what they have"

Something like, "They deserve to be resting on their laurels"

But without the negative connotations

Comment: Enjoy your achievements!

Comment: "out to pasture" ... ?

Comment: "Take a break to recharge [one's] batteries" and "Enjoy some well-deserved R&R after a heroic effort" may be suitable ways to convey the idea you have in mind.

Comment: "They deserve to be" actually flips the negative connotation. - "When *'rest on your laurels'* or, as it was initially, *'repose on your laurels'* was coined it was invariably part of a valedictory speech for some old soldier or retiring official." - "So thou, paternal Sage, may'st now repose. Nor seek new Laurels to adorn thy Brows." – [phrases.org.uk](https://www.phrases.org.uk/meanings/rest-on-his-laurels.html)

Answer (score 1):

You can use the expression

[well-earned](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/well-earned)

> fully deserved
>
> - a well-earned rest

(M-W)

- I hope they finally found time to settle down and enjoy a well-earned rest.

Answer (score 0):

I hope they have *gone fishing*.

> = To drop the duties of daily life and go do something else, something nice.
>
> [Urban dictionary](https://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=Gone%20Fishing)

The term was used in the past of eminent Chinese officials who, on leaving their posts with honour, were said to have retired to their estates to go fishing. {please forgive the lack of reference: it is difficult to find an authority for this}